# How to disable scientific notation in spark-xml

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, scientific-notation

How to disable to scientific notation while reading  the xml file using databrick spark-xml library.
Here is scenario, my XML file contain numeric value with space like this

```
<V1>42451267 </V1>
```

and what I'm getting 4.2451267E7 instead of 42451267

How can I fix it

My code and xml file are below

```
val xmlLocation = "sampleFile/xml/sample.xml"
val rootTag = "RTS"
val rowTag = "COLUMNTYPE"
val sqlContext = MySparkDriver.getSqlContext().
  read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
if (rootTag != null && rootTag.size == 0)
  sqlContext.option("rootTag", rootTag)
sqlContext.option("rowTag", rowTag)
val xmlDF = sqlContext.load(xmlLocation)
xmlDF.show(false)
```

output

```
[WrappedArray(4232323.0, 4.2451267E7),21-11-2000 01:04:34,NTS,212212112,100.0,100.0]
```

expected

```
[WrappedArray(4232323, 42451267),21-11-2000 01:04:34,NTS,212212112,100.0000,100.0000]
```

XML file

```
<RTS>
<COLUMNTYPE>
    <D1>
        <V1>4232323</V1>
        <V1>42451267 </V1>
        <V2>21-11-2000 01:04:34</V2>
        <V3>NTS</V3>
        <V4>212212112</V4>
        <V7>100.0000</V7>
        <V8>100.0000 </V8>

    </D1>
</COLUMNTYPE>
</RTS>
```

Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: If you want specific formatting don't use numbers. Use strings with desired format.

Comment: thanks for reply,but how can I decide data type

Comment: @zero323 plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isLong function of [TypeCast](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/9f681939d16508abf4a12a129469ffebf87a2fa4/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/xml/util/TypeCast.scala) class not able to predict datatype because your value "42451267 " contain space

However,If you want to treated as a long value defined your own custom schema where "V1" column data type is StringType

```
val xmlLocation = "sampleFile/xml/sample.xml"
val rootTag = "RTS"
val rowTag = "COLUMNTYPE"
val sqlContext = MySparkDriver.getSqlContext().
  read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
if (rootTag != null && rootTag.size == 0)
  sqlContext.option("rootTag", rootTag)
sqlContext.option("rowTag", rowTag)
```

Custom schema

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("D1", StructType(
    Seq(StructField("V1", ArrayType(StringType, true), true),
      StructField("V2", StringType, true),
      StructField("V3", StringType, true),
      StructField("V4", LongType, true),
      StructField("V7", DoubleType, true),
      StructField("V8", DoubleType, true))), true)))
sqlContext.schema(customSchema)
```

Create the udf for trim values

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val toTrim = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.map(_.trim()))
```

apply udf and type cast to long

```
val xmlDF = sqlContext.load(xmlLocation).select(struct(
  toTrim(col("D1.V1")).cast("array<long>").alias("V1"),
  col("D1.V2"), col("D1.V3"), col("D1.V4"), col("D1.V7"), col("D1.V8"))
  .alias("D1"))
xmlDF.printSchema
xmlDF.show(false)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure what is the point of all of that but I see basically two choices here:

- if all fields can be interpreted as big integer or you goal is to have these as integers you use type casting what should give more or less what you want without significant loss of functionality:

  ```
  case class D1(
    v1: Seq[Double], v2: String, v3: String, v4: Long, v7: Double, v8: Double
  )
  case class ColumnType(d1: D1)

  val df = Seq(ColumnType(D1(
    Seq(4232323, 42451267), 
    "21-11-2000 01:04:34",
    "NTS",
    212212112,
    100.0000,
    100.0000
  ))).toDF()

  df.select(struct(
    $"d1.v1".cast("array<bigint>").alias("v1"),
    $"d1.v2", $"d1.v3", $"d1.v4", $"d1.v7", $"d1.v8"
  ).alias("d1"))
  ```
- if you want a specific number format for presentation reasons you can convert data to an array of formated strings:

  ```
  val toFormatted = udf((xs: Seq[Double]) => xs.map(x => f"$x%4.0f"))

  df.select(struct(
    toFormatted($"d1.v1").alias("v1"),
    $"d1.v2", $"d1.v3", $"d1.v4", $"d1.v7", $"d1.v8"
  ).alias("d1"))
  ```